# Unificar una lista en python

Tags: python, string, lista

Hola quiero unificar una lista que tiene valores (list) y (str) en la misma. Por ejemplo:

```
A=[9, 3, '7', '3'] 
#y quiero obtener todos los valores tipo list ----> 
A=[9, 3, 7, 3]
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Con una comprensión de lista lo puedes hacer:

```py
A=[9, 3, '7', '3']
A = [int(num) for num in A]
```

Si deseas con un ciclo `for`

```py
nueva = []
A=[9, 3, '7', '3'] 

for num in A:
    nueva.append(int(num))
```

Esto solo funciona si todos los string pueden ser llevados a base 10 (por defecto al usar `int()`)

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme

Comment: de nada :D, como recomendación es bueno hacer una búsqueda rápida en Google antes de hacer tu pregunta.